# Надо сделать картинки на сайте. Как сделать картинки вместо обычных кружков планет?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Надо сделать картинки на сайте. Как сделать картинки вместо обычных кружков планет?
Помогите пожалуйста
Как вместо кружков планет сделать картинки?
codepen.io/Sergey1712/pen/aqqMvd

Comment: спасибо, еще вопрос, как убрать обводку?

Comment: когда меняю картинку, появляется обводка

Comment: и прозрачный фон, и пнг

Comment: так, хрен с ним, у меня перестали работать ссылки, работают ток первая планета и последняя

Comment: да, у меня код примерно одинаковый для всех планет, но даже без картинок не работает

Comment: Ну попробуйте обновить страницу, но хотя бы сберегите предыдущие картинки. У меня тоже разок было подвисло..

Comment: Да пробовал обновлять, изменения постепенно не сохранял придется к 3ем планетам откатывать